# Can we replace ASP.NET MVC with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the ASP.NET Web API and while learning, a question comes in mind that can i replace ASP.NET MVC with ASP.NET WEB API .For instance let's  say I am creating small application by using:

- UI Will be in : ASP.NET/HTML Controls, JavaScript,CSS.
- Server side code : ASP.NET MVC.
- Back End : SQL Server.

Now Can I use Web API instead of ASP.NET MVC and my new stack will be like:

- UI : HTML , JavaScript,CSS.
- Server side code: ASP.NET Web API.
- Back End : SQL Server.

Comment: if you are looking for yes/no answer, yes you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Might be recommended if you don’t plan on using any of the views that can be returned from MVC. With WebAPI you’ll be handling JSON in the client.